# Trying to write python CSV extractor

Tags: python, csv, logging

I am complete newbie for programming and this is my first real program I am trying to write.

So I have this huge CSV file (hundreds of cols and thousands of rows) where I am trying to extract only few columns based on value in the field. It works fine and I get nice output, but the problem arises when I am try to encapsulate the same logic in a function. 
it returns only first extracted row however print works fine.

I have been playing for this for hours and read other examples here and now my mind is mush.

```
import csv
import sys

newlogfile = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))
outLog = csv.writer(open('extracted.csv', 'w'))

def rowExtractor(logfile):
    for row in logfile:
        if row[32] == 'No':
            a = []
            a.append(row[44])
            a.append(row[58])
            a.append(row[83])
            a.append(row[32])
            return a

outLog.writerow(rowExtractor(newlogfile))
```

Comment: Could it be you're resetting your list to empty with each new row? What happens if you put the a = [] before the for? Also, the return will terminate you right after the first row as indicated by user457188. I'd place the return after for (same indentation).

Comment: please show when and how you call the rowExtractor function and where you put the print statement that works

Comment: @Gil.I if the print statement was where the return statement is it would print out all of the rows, because print won't break out of the function. I think that's what he's saying he did.

Comment: @Gil.I, exactly what dave said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exiting prematurely. When you put `return a` inside the `for` loop, return gets called on the first iteration. Which means that only the firs iteration runs.

A simple way to do this would be to do:

```
def rowExtractor(logfile):
    #output holds all of the rows
    ouput = []
    for row in logfile:
        if row[32] == 'No':
            a = []
            a.append(row[44])
            a.append(row[58])
            a.append(row[83])
            a.append(row[32])
            output.append(a)
    #notice that the return statement is outside of the for-loop
    return output
outLog.writerows(rowExtractor(newlogfile))
```

You could also consider using `yield`

Comment: ... and use `outLog.writerows()` instead of `outLog.writerow()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a return statement in your function...when it hits that line, it will return (thus terminating your loop). You'd need `yield` instead.

See [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Comment: I think he'd also need to switch to `.writerows`, but return->yield and adding the s should make the code work.

Comment: @DSM: Yes. It was more of a nudge in the right direction so he could see where the problem was.